# Modify label on view exposed filter

Tags: 8, views

I have a view with exposed filter to a field as follows :

[image]

I want to change the text '**Deployment date from**' and '**And**' to **`'From' and 'To'`**

Can i do this with **`hook_views_query_alter`** or **`hook_views_pre_render`**

Answer (score 5):

You can easily change the first label with the views editor, by setting it in Filter criteria part. But for the "And" i think you have it because you selected the "is between" operator.
So the easiest way to change it is to use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) our hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and change the '#title' of that second form field.

If you inspect the html of your field in front, you will see that it is in a  tag. So get the id of that form, for example

```
<form id="views-exposed-form-activities-page-1" ></form>
```

then in your_module.module file implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter():

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * This is your_module.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_activities_page_1_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['your_annoying_field']['#title'] = t('To'); //Instead of "And".
}
```

Comment: Yea i changed the first label from the view itself . For the second i didnt get the point you said . How can i access a view field in hook_form_alter ?

Comment: Ok, t did just update my answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: Its not working !! , am taking the id of the field (**'edit-created-min'**). Is that right or need to take the name ?

Comment: I will add as an answer , there was a mistake in taking the form_id from inspection

Comment: Yep, be carrefull with that id, i didn't test it but that was the idea. If you are not sure about the form'id then use `YOURMODULE_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)` and make `var_dump($form_id)`, this way you can maybe target it easily.

Answer (score 5):

Finally i got the answer . Actually it should be used like **`YOURMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter`** only . No need of **`activities_page_1_`** as expected . Am adding the answer below :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function module_name_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['created']['min']['#title'] = t('From');
  $form['created']['max']['#title'] = t('To');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with the String Overrides module. It's still under heavy development for Drupal 8 but MegaChriz (maintainer of the Feeds module a.o.) made a pretty stable version that you can download here:

https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/stringoverrides.zip

More information:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2236791#comment-8783307

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this with the following code.

Note that my field is actually called `field_date`, but to access the label I had to add "_value" to the end of my field to make it `field_date_value`.

Also note that `$form_id` for an exposed form is going to be generic. To check for a unique form ID, check `$form['#id']`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-unique-form-id') {  
    $form['field_date_value']['min']['#title'] = t('From');
    $form['field_date_value']['max']['#title'] = t('To');
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked a charm to bring custom sort order of date ranges in an exposed filter.